# (meta.status, ApiError)( elasticsearch.BadRequestError: BadRequestError(400, 'parsing_exception', 'Unknown key for a START_OBJECT in [knn].')

Tags: elasticsearch, llama-index

I am using llama index for a RAG and Elastic search for storing vector.
Using below sentence window function to encode embedding.

```
def get_sentence_window_query_engine(
    sentence_index,
    similarity_top_k=3,
    rerank_top_n=10,
):
    postproc = MetadataReplacementPostProcessor(target_metadata_key="window")
    rerank = SentenceTransformerRerank(
        top_n=rerank_top_n,
        model="C:\Project\Knowledge_search\BAAI/bge-reranker-base"
    )

    sentence_window_engine = sentence_index.as_query_engine(
        similarity_top_k=similarity_top_k, node_postprocessors=[postproc, rerank]
    )
```

index created successfully in the below format,

{
"embedding": [
0.0638020783662796,
.
.
0.0638020783662796,],
"content": "based artificial intelligence (AI) research organization founded in December 2015, researching artificial intelligence with the goal of developing "safe and beneficial" artificial general intelligence, which it defines as "highly autonomous systems that outperform humans at most economically valuable work".",
"metadata": {
"window": "OpenAI is a U.S.  based artificial intelligence (AI) research organization founded in December 2015, researching artificial intelligence with the goal of developing "safe and beneficial" artificial general intelligence, which it defines as "highly autonomous systems that outperform humans at most economically valuable work". [4] As one of the leading organizations of the AI spring,[5][6][7] it has developed several large language models, advanced image generation models, and previously, released open-source models. [8][9] Its release of ChatGPT has been credited with starting the AI spring.",
"original_text": "based artificial intelligence (AI) research organization founded in December 2015, researching artificial intelligence with the goal of developing "safe and beneficial" artificial general intelligence, which it defines as "highly autonomous systems that outperform humans at most economically valuable work".",
"*node_content": "{"id*": "d4ced45c-0183-478f-b870-e93f746855e7", "embedding": null, "metadata": {"window": "OpenAI is a U.S.  based artificial intelligence (AI) research organization founded in December 2015, researching artificial intelligence with the goal of developing \"safe and beneficial\" artificial general intelligence, which it defines as \"highly autonomous systems that outperform humans at most economically valuable work\". [4] As one of the leading organizations of the AI spring,[5][6][7] it has developed several large language models, advanced image generation models, and previously, released open-source models. [8][9] Its release of ChatGPT has been credited with starting the AI spring.", "original_text": "based artificial intelligence (AI) research organization founded in December 2015, researching artificial intelligence with the goal of developing \"safe and beneficial\" artificial general intelligence, which it defines as \"highly autonomous systems that outperform humans at most economically valuable work\"."}, "excluded_embed_metadata_keys": ["window", "original_text"], "excluded_llm_metadata_keys": ["window", "original_text"], "relationships": {"1": {"node_id": "3cd68e24-b96e-4859-a885-36b620b3215e", "node_type": "4", "metadata": {}, "hash": "f14b821e536e4c51b0e3bf63d37dfcda06994d82bfa1fc8dc376e6c2c3dc32e9", "class_name": "RelatedNodeInfo"}, "2": {"node_id": "35767df0-e30c-4403-9652-308c20f092df", "node_type": "1", "metadata": {"window": "OpenAI is a U.S.  based artificial intelligence (AI) research organization founded in December 2015, researching artificial intelligence with the goal of developing \"safe and beneficial\" artificial general intelligence, which it defines as \"highly autonomous systems that outperform humans at most economically valuable work\". [4] As one of the leading organizations of the AI spring,[5][6][7] it has developed several large language models, advanced image generation models, and previously, released open-source models.", "original_text": "OpenAI is a U.S. "}, "hash": "ff6cbcfd55602aa8ccde0f9cb1358af449e7e5bc9330c32017b6e10664c914e1", "class_name": "RelatedNodeInfo"}, "3": {"node_id": "744296cf-a55a-4bc7-9e1d-0c1a3388abd2", "node_type": "1", "metadata": {"window": "OpenAI is a U.S.  based artificial intelligence (AI) research organization founded in December 2015, researching artificial intelligence with the goal of developing \"safe and beneficial\" artificial general intelligence, which it defines as \"highly autonomous systems that outperform humans at most economically valuable work\". [4] As one of the leading organizations of the AI spring,[5][6][7] it has developed several large language models, advanced image generation models, and previously, released open-source models. [8][9] Its release of ChatGPT has been credited with starting the AI spring. [10]\n\n\n\nThe organization consists of the non-profit OpenAI, Inc.", "original_text": "[4] As one of the leading organizations of the AI spring,[5][6][7] it has developed several large language models, advanced image generation models, and previously, released open-source models."}, "hash": "95dd92b4e5d7418dc0404114599a348b12f60857af84a4936525d5a06eb24265", "class_name": "RelatedNodeInfo"}}, "hash": "7c0e3171d9f6a553df1643fa65e2a05b091df788e819abc97ed29c8079c1133c", "text": "", "start_char_idx": 17, "end_char_idx": 325, "text_template": "{metadata_str}\n\n{content}", "metadata_template": "{key}: {value}", "metadata_seperator": "\n", "class_name": "TextNode"}",
"_node_type": "TextNode",
"document_id": "3cd68e24-b96e-4859-a885-36b620b3215e",
"doc_id": "3cd68e24-b96e-4859-a885-36b620b3215e",
"ref_doc_id": "3cd68e24-b96e-4859-a885-36b620b3215e"
}
}

When I try to query inside elastic search this using this query:

```
sentence_index = build_sentence_window_index(
    document,
    llm,
    embed_model="local:C:\Project\Knowledge_search\BAAI/bge-small-en-v1.5",
    vector_store=vector_store
)
query_engine = get_sentence_window_query_engine(sentence_index=sentence_index)

    resp = query_engine.query(
        "tell me about DALL-E"
    )
```

I am getting this error:

raise HTTP_EXCEPTIONS.get(meta.status, ApiError)(elasticsearch.BadRequestError: BadRequestError(400, 'parsing_exception', 'Unknown key for a START_OBJECT in [knn].')

Comment: Hi Abhishek, Are you referring this example - https://docs.llamaindex.ai/en/stable/examples/vector_stores/Elasticsearch_demo.html#basic-example ? Just i am trying to reproduce on my side.

Comment: No, I am referring this :https://medium.com/@shivansh.kaushik/advanced-text-retrieval-with-elasticsearch-llamaindex-sentence-window-retrieval-cb5ea720aa44